# Draw circles on mathjax

Tags: support, mathjax

How can I draw a small circle in mathjax? I know that I can do it with `\bullet` that gives: $\bullet$ but I want it more big, can I do that? I tried `\ocircle` and `\circle` but it does not work.

Only `\circ` that gives $\circ$ is work but I need a bigger one

Comment: well, you can do a $\Huge \circ$ ``\Huge \circ``, a  ``\Huge \bullet`` $\Huge \bullet$ or a $\Huge \bigcirc$ ``\Huge \bigcirc``

Comment: `\bigcirc`: $\bigcirc$

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot

Comment: even bigger (at least on the editor): $\Huge \bigodot$ ``\Huge \bigodot``

Comment: You might be interested to have a look here: http://www.kau.edu.sa/Files/0004817/Files/59535_Symbols.pdf

Comment: Next week on meta.math.SE: "I want to draw the Mona Lisa using MathJax, how can I do that?"

Comment: There's also the non-standard enclose macro, e.g. $\require{enclose}\enclose{circle}{\enclose{box}{x}}$

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger how did you do that?

Comment: Right-click to get the TeX source? And see http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#enclose