# How to write an encircled bullet?

Tags: support, mathjax

How can I write in MathJax a circle with a bullet inside it? I know \odot, but this is a circle with a dot inside it; I want most of the circle be filled by the dark circle inside and only a thin clear rim surrounding it.

Comment: $\bigodot\kern-0.975em\bullet$ which lends itself to $$\Large\stackrel{\bigodot\kern-0.975em\bullet\bigodot\kern-0.975em\bullet}{\Huge\smile}$$

Comment: The bullet isn't quite centered, @Asaf ;P   Seriously though, nice work

Comment: Smiley is looking to her left!

Comment: @AsafKaragila if I add "\Large" to \bullet, the resulting larger bullet is not in the center?

Comment: @Asaf, The problem is that its not perfectly centered.

Comment: @Zuhair Adjust the kerning to your taste:  $\bigodot\kern-0.9em\bullet \quad \bigodot\kern-0.8em\bullet \quad \bigodot\kern-0.7em\bullet \quad \bigodot\kern-0.96em\bullet \quad \bigodot\kern-0.5em\bullet$ (these run from -0.9em to -0.5 em)  $\bigodot\kern-0.835em\bullet$ `$\bigodot\kern-0.835em\bullet$` looks okay to me...

Comment: @Xander  Is .835 the fourth from the left?  That looks pretty centered, more or less, in terms of horizontally.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what mathematical operation is this going to represent? Has it been found or used in other books/papers/PDFs?

Comment: Surprisingly, even `$\require{enclose}\enclose{circle}{\bullet}$`$\require{enclose}\enclose{circle}{\bullet}$ doesn't look great (which I found from [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22564/draw-circles-on-mathjax)

Comment: @amWhy I don't think so.  I believe that the last one (which is not in the group with the others) is -0.835em.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer on a quick google, I only saw that its used as a fancy bullet on some twitter posts, some Thai tourism site, and an [engineering book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Py7bP.jpg). In the case of OP, Zuhair has been exploring the idea of creating new notation [link1 (Math.SE)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4378595/reference-request-had-those-notations-for-quantification-been-explored-before), [link2. (MO)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/415653/what-is-the-basis-for-the-quantifier-notation).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Mathjax, it is hard to overlay characters and get them perfectly aligned on all screens. ($\rm\LaTeX$ has [purpose-built](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/stackengine) packages.) Instead, you can use the following Unicode character (which Mathjax allows):

```
⦿
CIRCLED BULLET
Unicode: U+29BF, UTF-8: E2 A6 BF
```

`$$a⦿b. ⦿^{⦿^{⦿^{⦿}}}.\Huge ⦿.$$` gives
$$a⦿b. ⦿^{⦿^{⦿^{⦿}}}.\Huge ⦿.$$
It even comes with the spacing of a binary operator,
`$a⦿b$ $a{⦿}b$`$a⦿b$ $a{⦿}b$

Here's a screenshot of the above using two different renderers, HTML-CSS (with my preinstalled XITS font):

> [image]

and common HTML:

> [image]

If you don't want to copy-paste and have good memory, one can type `\unicode{x29bf}`$\unicode{x29bf}$  for the same effect. (This works for other Unicode symbols, [e.g.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33302/double-struck-1-in-mathjax/33303#33303) `\unicode{x1D7D9}`$\unicode{x1D7D9}$. I am both lazy and forgetful, so I [use software](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30364/is-there-any-way-to-have-comment-templates-whenever-we-are-typing-comments/33153#33153).)

- Some other circled Unicode symbols: $⊕⊖⊗⊘⊙⊚⊛⊜⊝⨀⨁⨂⨷⨸⦶⦷⦸⦹⦺⦻⦼⦽⦾⦿⧀⧁$.
- I couldn't find a big version to make the equivalent of `$⨀\limits_a^b$`$⨀\limits_a^b$, but Davide Cervone [in the comments below](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34555/how-to-write-an-encircled-bullet#comment160864_34558) has given the following beautiful suggestion (copied verbatim)

> You might consider `\mathop{\vcenter{\huge ⦿}}_{n=1}^{\infty}` as more semantic and a little easier to use, plus it centers the operator, and \limits will work with that:
> $$\mathop{\vcenter{\huge ⦿}}_{n=1}^{\infty} abc$$
> Even better might be `\mathop{\vcenter{\huge\unicode[.67,.15]{x29BF}}}_{n=1}^{\infty}`, which specifies the height and depth of the character so that the limits can be better placed (though this may depend on the fonts that the viewer has installed).

Comment: You might consider `\mathop{\vcenter{\huge ⦿}}_{n=1}^{\infty}` as more semantic and a little easier to use, plus it centers the operator, and `\limits` will work with that: $$\mathop{\vcenter{\huge ⦿}}_{n=1}^{\infty} abc$$  Even better might be `\mathop{\vcenter{\huge\unicode[.67,.15]{x29BF}}}_{n=1}^{\infty}`, which specifies the height and depth of the character so that the limits can be better placed (though this may depend on the fonts that the viewer has installed).

Comment: @DavideCervone thank you $\vcenter{\stackrel{⦿{\tiny \triangle} ⦿}{\smile}}$ I have added this verbatim to the answer.

Comment: Love the smile face!